# How to Filter a domain name in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, telecommunication, google-analytics-filters

So I have a website with two domain names:

www.domain_a.com and www.domain_b.com

Users see and use www.domain_a.com while the staff monitor and work on www.domain_b.com. They're both connected to the same database.

I want to use Google Analytics Filters so everybody from domain_b.com will be excluded from the analytics report. We think it's the easiest way to filter out everybody working on the site.

I tried implementing this with a Custom Filter, Filter Field = Campaign Target URL, and the Filter Pattern = domain_b. This does not work...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help is great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try like below filter

[image]